# Wait for an Comport value inside a other thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've created a small program. Everthing works fine but now I have recognized that I have to wait for an comport input and here I stuck .

Here is my `DataReceived` thread:

```
void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    RxString = serialPort.ReadLine();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
    void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
String RxString1 = RxString+("\n");

 if (RxString1 == "END\n") {
    stopauto = "stop";
    autostart.Enabled = true;
    autostop.Enabled = false;
}
```

Here the if with end and other things works fine.

But now I have another thread, inside which I have to wait for an comport input to receive , eg: "go".

I don't post the whole code it has near 200 lines ...

```
 private void AutostartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 .... Do some Code
... Here i want to wait for "go"
... If go is received go ahead
}
```

I have tried it with a while and while and a if ... but this will not work because inside the while I receive nothing from the comport .

Then  played around with `AutoResetEvent` , but it stucks too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Here is my `DataReceived` thread" That isn't a thread.

Comment: The DataReceived event is useful when you *don't* have a thread that requires serial port input.  It gets actively harmful when you *do* have such a thread, that requires you to co-ordinate two separate threads.  You'll have close to zero odds of getting that right when you use global variables like *RxString*.  Simply remove your event handler and use ReadLine() directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution ... maybe not the best way but it works.

With ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent it always freeze.

I think the problem was that i was in a while loop and so the wait handler was never signaled so it freeze at this point.

Now i work with a global variable, a simple if in the DisplayText event and a while which calls this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText)); and it works without any problems.

Here is the Serialport and DisplayText Code:

```
String waitvar = ""; // Global wait Variable  

void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
RxString = serialPort.ReadLine();
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
}

void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
String RxString1 = RxString+("\n");

if (RxString1 == "go\n") {
   waitvar = "go";
}
comview.AppendText(RxString1);
}
```

And at the Wait point:

```
private void AutostartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
.... Do some Code

// Wait here

while (waitvar != "go")
{
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
}

.... Do some Code
}
```

Thank you to all helpers !

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following: As the `DataReceived` event of the `SerialPort` component is executed in a separate thread, you are safe to assume that it will be executed even though your main thread waits.

This allows you to set a `WaitHandle` if the required "keyword" is received, and you can wait for this event to occur:

```
private ManualResetEvent _goReceived = new ManualResetEvent(false); // Initialize as "not set"

void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    RxString = serialPort.ReadLine();

    // DO NOT CALL DISPLAYTEXT IF YOU RECEIVE "GO" - THE MAIN THREAD IS BLOCKED!
    if (RxString.StartsWith("go"))
    {
        _goReceived.Set();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
}

void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    String RxString1 = RxString+("\n");

    if (RxString1 == "END\n") {
       stopauto = "stop";
       autostart.Enabled = true;
       autostop.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

In your method that should wait for "go", just wait for the event to occur:

```
private void AutostartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .... Do some Code

    // Wait for "go" and THEN call DisplayText instead of calling
    // it above
    _goReceived.Wait();
    DisplayText();

    // Reset the event to make this works more than just once
    _goReceived.Reset();

    ... If go is received go ahead
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer.

I Think you mean _goReceived.OneWait(); ...

I have tried to implement this but its the same as with the AutoResetEvent ... the whole application freez :-(

The if if (RxString.StartsWith("go")) work in my code but when i run it with _goReceived.Set(); and _goReceived.Onewait(); the code stuck at goReceived.Onewait(); and goReceived.Wait(); will not be signaled ...